# Installation of MongoDB failing on Mac OSX Snow Leopard

Tags: mongodb, osx-snow-leopard, macports

Firstly the installation take hours and then it throws and error. 
Following was the log trace. It is failing while building Python module

```
'cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_mongodb/work/mongodb-src-r1.6.5" && scons -j2 all mongobridge mongosniff --usesm --cxx=/usr/bin/g++-4.2 --full'
:info:build sh: line 0: cd: /opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_mongodb/work/mongodb-src-r1.6.5: No such file or directory
:info:build shell command " cd "/opt/local/var/macports/build/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_mongodb/work/mongodb-src-r1.6.5" && scons -j2 all mongobridge mongosniff --usesm --cxx=/usr/bin/g++-4.2 --full " returned error 1
:error:build Target org.macports.build returned: shell command failed (see log for details)
:debug:build Backtrace: shell command failed (see log for details)
    while executing
"command_exec build"
    (procedure "portbuild::build_main" line 8)
    invoked from within
"$procedure $targetname"
:info:build Warning: the following items did not execute (for mongodb): org.macports.activate org.macports.build org.macports.destroot org.macports.install
:notice:build Log for mongodb is at: /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_databases_mongodb/main.log
```

Comment: Can you please post the build log mentioned in the error message?

Comment: Its not really recommended to install MongoDB via MacPorts which compiles from scratch. You may be better off getting an official binary or using homebrew.

Comment: @Brendan Yeah i realized and did the same. It hardly took any minutes

Comment: haha, I get a similar error when trying to install my homebrew port of dbxml.  I'll make a post if I figure out why

Comment: Please provide more details - your Portfile, which command is causing it to fail exactly (i believe that output is from `sudo port -d install mongodb` right?), your version of MacPorts (have you tried updating the MacPorts repository lately?) - it works for me on SL (now on Lion, equipped with the latest (beta) version of MacPorts)